# breaklines doesn't work with \mintinline

Tags: line-breaking, minted

I **try to get line-wrapping to work with `\mintinline`**, like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{minted}

\setmintedinline{
                bgcolor=lightgray,
                }

\begin{document}

\mintinline[breaklines, bgcolor=lightgray]{java}{test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test}

\end{document}
```

I also tried setting

- `\setmintedinline{breaklines}`
- `\newmintinline{java}{breaklines}`

But the code won't wrap. I read [here (github)](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31) and [here (docu)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minted/minted.pdf), that `\mintinline` should allow for `breaklines`-option.

Also this

```
\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\minted@inputpyg}{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\minted@PYGstyle%
    \csname PYG\minted@get@opt{style}{default}\endcsname
  \VerbatimPygments{\PYG}{\minted@PYGstyle}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{minted@isinline}}%
   {\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@get@opt{breaklines}{false}}{true}}%
    {\let\FV@BeginVBox\relax
     \let\FV@EndVBox\relax
     \def\FV@BProcessLine##1{%
       \FancyVerbFormatLine{%
         \FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereHook
         \FancyVerbFormatText{\FancyVerbBreakStart##1\FancyVerbBreakStop}}}%
     \minted@inputpyg@inline}%
    {\minted@inputpyg@inline}}%
   {\minted@inputpyg@block}%
}
\makeatother
```

[was suggested](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31#issuecomment-361010857) by [Geoffrey Poore (gpoore)](https://github.com/gpoore) as a workaround for `\mintinline` to allow `breakafter`-option on [github](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31).

I tried it, but it didn't work for me. Maybe `breaklines` dosn't work in the first place.

How can I check the version of `minted` and whats the current version?

I checked Pygments instelled version, it's `2.2.0`. Seems to be the current version.

Any ideas, why the lines won't wrap?

Comment: The only supported option for breaklines with mintinline is breakbytoken[anywhere], not breakafter.

Comment: @TeXnician Here https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31#issuecomment-361010857 gpoore claims to have the workaround posted in the question

Comment: In my experiment, `breaklines` works; also `breakafter=.` or `breakanywhere`. Of course, the line must fit in the case of `breakafter=.`, which could be a problem with a monospaced font.

Comment: @egreg are you using `\mintinline`? Because I can get it to work with `\begin{minted}`, but that's not the question. Maybe I have some wrong setting or I miss something.

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux Can you tell what version of `minted` you are running?

Comment: @egreg how do I find this out?

Comment: Look in the log file for `minted.sty`

Comment: @egreg Thanks. It says `\ProvidesPackage{minted}
    [2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX]` so I guess it's version 2.5 (current version).

Answer (score 8):

It seems like this has been fixed in the `minted` package. Using the options `breaklines` and `breakafter` causes a line break for the source code.

```
\mintinline[breaklines, breakafter=_]{python}{very_long_class_name}
```

Answer (score 2):

**2018/03/16**

This is a well known problem, which is [documented](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minted/minted.pdf) (search for `bgcolor`) ([bug report](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/194)):

`bgcolor` only works with `\begin{minted}`, but not with `\mintinline`. If used with `\mintinline`, `breaklines` doesn't work.

Regarding the [code, that should allow for `breakafter` with `\mintinline`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31#issuecomment-361010857):

It doesn't work, because its ["such a long string of text with only a single possible hyphenation point". The solution](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/31#issuecomment-373579402) is to add this code (possibly without the `\begingroup`):

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 1 fil}
<paragraph with \mintedinline that won't normally break>
\endgroup
```